# 覚えました - Can it mean "I learned"?

Tags: translation, verbs, anime

> 俺サーブとブロックはあの人を見て覚えました

The above sentence is taken straight from Haikyuu!! S01E07.

The subs translate to "I learned serving and blocking by watching him play".

Does 覚えました give the "I learned" part of the translation?

Also, how does 俺 change the vibe of the sentence? does it put emphasis on the fact that its the speaker's serving and blocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 俺サーブとブロックはあの人を見て覚えました

覚える can mean "learn (how to do something)" "acquire/master (a technique)".
[プログレッシブ和英中辞典](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E8%A6%9A%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B/#je-8910) says:

> おぼえる【覚える】
>   2〔学ぶ，体得する〕learn
>   「こつを覚える」 learn [get] the knack (of it)
>   「車の運転を覚える」 learn how to drive a car
>   「その説明書を読めば、使い方はすぐ覚えられる」 Read the instructions, and you will understand at once how to use it.

俺 is the subject of the action 覚えました.

Breakdown:

> 俺(は) -- "I"
>   サーブとブロックは -- "serving and blocking" (object of 覚えました)
>   あの人を見て -- "by watching that person"
>   覚えました -- "learned/acquired/mastered (how to do...)"

Comment: Is the 俺 here short for 俺は or 俺の?  My (admittedly non-expert) reading of this would be that it's part of "my serving and blocking" (that is, 俺**の**サーブとブロック), rather than 俺 being an explicit subject (and the "I" subject is just implied)..?

Comment: @Foogod It's not 「俺(の)サーブとブロック」.  This の can't be omitted. It's 「俺(は)～～」, where 俺 is the subject. This は is very often omitted in casual conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. 覚えました can also mean learned. Because most of the time I would ask someone’s name, they will say it and then I will say 覚えました！
俺 is mostly used by males. I personally don’t use it because it sounds arrogant.